# Reload PJAX container inside modal dialog using Yii2 and Jquery

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

I'm having some issues reloading a `PJAX` container inside a custom `modal` much like bootstrap's `modal`.

The goal of this code is to reload the pjax container to reload all submitted **comments** inside the `pjax`'s `Listview`.

The initial reload is performed by `jQuery` but followed by an exception raised in `jquery.pjax.js`:

```
jquery.pjax.js:740 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
```

which is part of a function named extractContainer:

```
  if (fullDocument) {
    var $head = $(parseHTML(data.match(/<head[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/head>/i)[0]))
    var $body = $(parseHTML(data.match(/<body[^>]*>([\s\S.]*)<\/body>/i)[0])) <-- error
  } else {
    var $head = $body = $(parseHTML(data))
  }
```

My view's pjax:

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
'id'=>'pjax-post-comments',
'timeout' => 5000,
'enableReplaceState'=>false,
'enablePushState'=>false,
'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false],
]);?>
<?php
$query = $model->findComments();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 2, //for development reasons
    ],
]);?>
<div class='resp-col col-12 post-item-comment-history'>
    <?=ListView::widget([
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'summary'=>false,
     'itemOptions' => [
         'class' => 'comment-item'
     ],
     'itemView' => '/frontend/comment/_item',
    ]);?>
</div>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
```

My view's jquery call to reload the pjax container:

```
$('#submit-comment').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var user_id = '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->id?>';
    var content = $('#comment-content').val();
    var post_id = '<?=$model->id?>';
    var associative_id = $(this).data('assoc-id');
    $.post('/frontend/post/submit-comment', {
        user_id : user_id,
        post_id : post_id,
        content : content,
        associative_id: associative_id
    }, function(response){
        if(response['response'] == true){
            $('#comment-content').removeClass('error-form');
            $('#comment-content').addClass('success-form');
            $(this).data('assoc-id','null');
            $('#comment-content').val('');
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#pjax-post-comments",timeout: 5000});
        }
        else{
            alert(response['errors']);
            $('#comment-content').addClass('error-form');
            $('#comment-content').removeClass('succes-form');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the server response, does it even have that containe?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply. Your comment pointed me into the right direction. The pjax received URL did not match with the modal's url. See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Beowulfenator, I was put onto the right track for fixing this issue.

Apparently the `pjax` module returned the URL of the actual `page` BEHIND the `modal` `/frontend/index` instead of `/frontend/post/detail?id=id`. Routing the `modal`'s `pjax` to the correct url was fairly easy:

```
 $('#submit-comment').on('click',function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var user_id = '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->id?>';
        var content = $('#comment-content').val();
        var post_id = '<?=$model->id?>';
        var associative_id = $(this).data('assoc-id');
        $.post('/frontend/post/submit-comment', {
            user_id : user_id,
            post_id : post_id,
            content : content,
            associative_id: associative_id
        }, function(response){
            if(response['response'] == true){
                $('#comment-content').removeClass('error-form');
                $('#comment-content').addClass('success-form');
                $(this).data('assoc-id','null');
                $('#comment-content').val('');
                $.pjax.reload(
{
container:"#pjax-post-comments",
url: '/frontend/post/detail?id=<?=$model->id?>', //manually added the url
timeout: 5000
}
); 
            }
            else{
                alert(response['errors']);
                $('#comment-content').addClass('error-form');
                $('#comment-content').removeClass('succes-form');
            }
        });
    });
```

EDIT: The downside to this is that the script must be INSIDE the pjax for the code to be operational. The downside to THAT is that I have to reinitialise the click every time, otherwise the `$('#submit-comment').on('click',function());` will click cumulative So here's how to fix that:

```
$('#submit-comment').on('click',function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(this).unbind('click'); 
    alert('');
    var user_id = '<?=Yii::$app->user->identity->id?>';
    var content = $('#comment-content').val();
    var post_id = '<?=$model->id?>';
    var associative_id = $(this).data('assoc-id');
    $.post('/frontend/post/submit-comment', {
        user_id : user_id,
        post_id : post_id,
        content : content,
        associative_id: associative_id
    }, function(response){
        if(response['response'] == true){

            $('#comment-content').removeClass('error-form');
            $('#comment-content').addClass('success-form');
            $(this).data('assoc-id','null');
            $('#comment-content').val('');
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#pjax-post-comments",url: '/frontend/post/detail?id=<?=$model->id?>',replace:false,timeout: 5000});
            init();
        }
        else{
            alert(response['errors']);
            $('#comment-content').addClass('error-form');
            $('#comment-content').removeClass('succes-form');
        }
    });
});
```